# Como fazer um "for each" no SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreach

Possuo uma tabela A com *n* registros. Para cada registro desta tabela, quero pegar a informação de um campo *x* para fazer um `select` e, a partir dos dados resultados deste `select`, fazer um `insert` em uma tabela B. Só que preciso fazer isso para todos os *n* registros de A.

Como faço isso no SQLite? Tem algo semelhante a um "for each" para esta situação? Ou só dá pra fazer essa operação por uma aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O SQLite é um banco de dados e não uma linguagem de programação, a linguagem de consulta, portanto declarativa que tem nele permite algo semelhante que é o `select` que já conhece. O `for each` é tipicamente imperativo.

É possível estender o SQLite para aceitar outras coisas. Ele é de código aberto e até tem algumas facilidades para incluir personalizações. Então você poderia criar uma espécie de *stored procedure* ou extensão do SQL contido nele. Claro, não não é algo simples de fazer. Poderia ser em C, uma linguagem própria, uma alteração do SQL padrão ou outra linguagem, como Lua, C#, ou outra já conhecida, cada uma com suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Portanto é mais fácil fazer a consulta de forma simples e e depois manipular na aplicação. Por isso que entender bem tudo o que dá para fazer em uma *query* pode ajudar filtrar só o que deseja. Eu vejo muitas consultas ruins em códigos por aí, incluindo de pessoas experientes. Em parte porque o modelo de consulta do SQL não ajuda, por isso muitos vão para o NoSQL, mas muitas vezes por motivos errados.

Dito tudo isto é possível fazer um `insert` baseado em um `select`, ou seja, a fonte de dados do `insert` pode ser o resultado de um `select`. Como a pergunta não diz o que precisa , não pude ajudar mais. Exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO b (meuX) VALUES (x)
    SELECT x FROM a;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/SelectBased.sql).

Comment: Ajudou, Maniero!  Obrigado!

Comment: Quando eu uso `INSERT-SELECT`, não uso `INSERT-VALUES-SELECT`. Não conhecia essa sintaxe com o `VALUES` antes do `SELECT`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Em muitos, casos, inclusive esse bem simples, não precisa mesmo, mas tem vários que só pode ser assim, porque pode não haver uma relação direta, precisa mapear